# phonegap cloud build with single codebase with different ios and android plugins

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

we have successfully created a decent phonegap application working on android and iphone. (using eclipse android dev environment and running phonegap cloud build)

But I have integrated a Github plugin which was specific to Android "Sharing Plugin" .For that I had included Share.java file and other javascript file. But how will I integrate ios share plugin in same codebase (eclipse project) or I will have to Copy entire code on Mac machine use xCode Dev environment and use the plugin that way I will end up making two builds (only HTML, JS ,CSS common) and I will be using two Builds on Adobe Cloud Build service.

IS there any way to keep a single Source base for iOS and Android for even plugins? (put .m .h files of ios plugin in same eclipse codebase and use adobe phonegap build and use the plugin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are planning on using PhoneGap Build service, they only support a [limited set of plugins](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins). You will not be able to import this plugin with PhoneGap build.

If you switch to building locally, this will invariably split your code into two projects (one for Android and one for iOS). You can create symlinks and keep www assets in a single location, but native code will be split (including your plugins).

Comment: Ok No problem by native code is split for iOS and android But Now I can use phonegap cloud build for both codebases separately. (actually our goal is to keep 2 GIT Repos for ios and android and build there code via cloud)

Comment: why do we want it..?
we are creating apk ipa files as per Client basis with same app...just some theme and logo changes. So we will git commit the theme files into codebases and run the 2 builds on cloud publish apps per client basis.

Comment: @kxb Do that means I cannot have single android Zxing plugin codebase that built into IOS app via phonegap cloud build service?

Comment: @Roylee PhoneGap build has a barcode scanner plugin (I think that is Zxing). If you use Build, you don't need it locally (I presume that's what you mean by Zxing plugin codebase).